# Memory error at python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from __future__ import division
import dataProcess
import csv,re
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
#######################################################################################
#                   Pruning of N-grams depending upon the frequency of tags           #                                                       
#######################################################################################

for k in range(2,8):
    filename="Dataset/Cross/N_gram_Features_Pruned/"+str(k)+"_gram.txt"
    filewrite=open(filename,"w")
    CSV_tag_reader=csv.reader(open("Dataset/Cross/N_grams_recored/"+str(k)+"_gram.csv","r"),delimiter=',')
    header_data=CSV_tag_reader.next();    
    table = [row for row in CSV_tag_reader]
    values=[]
    result_tag=[]
    for j in range(0,len(header_data)):
        sum1=0
        avg1=0
        for i in range (0,3227):
            sum1=sum1+int(table[i][j])
    ##    print "************************************************************"
    ##    print sum1
        avg1=sum1/3227
    ##    print avg1
        if(avg1>=0.3):
            result_tag.append(header_data[j])
    print len(header_data)
    print len(result_tag)
    print "************************************************************"
    filewrite.write(str(result_tag))
```

My code is to count frequency of particular word in 3227 samples of data.i have record about 277436 words frequency in 3227 samples.so image csv file with 3227 rows and 60k columns.so am reading each word and sum the frequency and find the average..bt am getting memory error when am running this code?how can i solve?

> ```
> Error:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "N_gram_pruning.py", line 15, in <module>
>     table = [row for row in CSV_tag_reader]
> MemoryError
> ```

My csv file like thisss

```
f1 f2 f3  f4.....f277436(header row)
0  9  1    4      70
56 2  66   8      23
(3227 rows...)
```

Comment: so... 3227 * 60k, = 193,620,000 records. Don't you think that's just a little bit much to be stuffing into the memory?

Comment: I'm also confused -- `for k in range(6,7)` is simply `k=6`

Comment: ya i knw bt what to do? i have this much data..

Comment: If you're having a memory error, you should use a generator instead of a list. However I haven't done enough work with `csv.reader` to really know what data structure you're getting out. Can you do `print(CSV_tag_reader[0])` and tell me what it looks like? I can guide you through making a generator that will sum and average your word counts.

Comment: Honestly, even `type(CSV_tag_reader[0])` will be fine if I have some idea of what I'm working with. Is each element a row of your CSV data in the form of a list of columns? That's how I'd do it, but...

Comment: i'd read the csv file in line by line, and sort it into a database structure. it won't fit in memory, but you can use the `dbm` module to create a dict-looking object that is on disk instead.

Comment: @adsmith  : Did you mean <blockquote><pre><code> for data in CSV_tag_reader: 
                                               print data[0]
</code></pre></blockquote>
output:

    9
    0
    8
    7
type(data[0]) is str

each row in csv is column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the average for each column, there is no need to load the whole thing into memory. Do something like

```
with open(filename) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    tags = next(csvreader)
    sums = [0] * len(tags)
    for count, row in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        sums = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums, row)]
avgs = [x / count for x in sums]
result_tags = [h for (h, a) in zip(tags, avgs) if a > 0.3]
```

Comment: i want column's hedaer whose avgs is greater than 0.3 how can i extract

Comment: `[h for (h, a) in zip(headers, avgs) if a > 0.3]`

Comment: I updated the code, it now reads the first CSV line as the tags and finds the relevant ones in the last line

Comment: @ rmartinjak can i find the number of non zero values in columns using this code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're reading the entire file into memory. To avoid this, you may have to restructure your algorithm. It seems that you're operating on every column individually, meaning operations on each column are independent. Therefore, if you transpose your csv files so they can be read line by line, you can iterate over those lines rather than reading them all into memory.

Alternatively, you could use [file.seek()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek), though it'll be very slow.